# Woocommerce rating not showing in new custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on to new custom theme. I have installed  woocommerce plugin. I have import product from xml files. I had tried to test rating functionality. Its working on wordpress default theme twentytwelve, twentysixteen. etc. But when I switched to my custom theme. comment section not showing rating.

Take a look on screenshot. Comment section has only textarea.

Here is my code of comments.php

```
<div class="comments">
    <?php if (post_password_required()) : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Post is password protected. Enter the password to view any comments.', 'html5blank' ); ?></p>
</div>

    <?php return; endif; ?>

<?php if (have_comments()) : ?>

    <h2><?php comments_number(); ?></h2>

    <ul>
        <?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=html5blankcomments'); // Custom callback in functions.php ?>
    </ul>

<?php elseif ( ! comments_open() && ! is_page() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) : ?>

    <p><?php _e( 'Comments are closed here.', 'html5blank' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php comment_form(); ?>

</div>
```

[image: my screenshot]

Comment: Anybody master here? anybody professional here?

Comment: Are you overriding any WooCommerce templates in your theme? Does your theme has 'woocommerce.php' in root?

Comment: @OutsourceWordPress I have not override any woocommerce file in my theme. I wonder how "twentysixteen" theme has inbuilt functionality that show rating without overriding woocommerce.php file.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know.

Comment: vrajesh, you're using the [HTML5 Blank](http://html5blank.com/) theme, which *by default does **not** have support for WooCommerce*. So although certain WooCommerce content still appear, other content would likely not appear (as they're supposed to be). You can fix that via the `add_theme_support()` code *as in @OutsourceWordPress's answer*, or [see this guide by the WooCommerce team](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Declaring-WooCommerce-support-in-themes).

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank you so much for your guidance. you are best.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might need to declare **WooCommerce support** if you are using custom theme in order to make it compatible with WooCommerce. Default WordPress themes would be normally compatible with WooCommerce and they will work without adding anything. You can read more here -
https://woocommerce.com/document/third-party-theme-compatibility/.

**Step 1:** Add this to your theme's 'functions.php'.

```
function custom_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_setup' );
```

**Step 2:** If still reviews not showing, copy your theme's 'page.php' as 'woocommerce.php'. Remove the loop - `<?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>` and `<?php endwhile; endif; ?>`. Replace `the_content()` with `woocommerce_content()`.

Let me know whether these fixes the issue, else paste new 'woocommerce.php' contents in your question.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. But my question is why should I add your custom code ? all free premium theme support woocommerece rating without add any code. So where I made mistake. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I marked as checked. Genius! Master!

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating custom theme then you have to copy templates from woocommerce to your custom theme then add folder name `woocommerce` to your custom theme.

Then copy `single-product-reviews.php` from plugins -> woocommerce -> templates and paste it to your custom theme newly created folder name `woocommerce`

Now you can customize your review template as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a Setting issue in WooCommerce. Go to WooCommerce Menu, then to Settings -> Products Tab. You can find the options to Enable Rating and Review. Please check the screenshot.

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Its already checked : http://prntscr.com/kaeyu2 . As per question, When I change theme to twentysixteen It  shows me star rating http://prntscr.com/kaf0fc

Comment: I have face these issue whenever I create new theme. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @vrajesh if you have created your own theme, does it supports woocommerce? If not Outsource WordPress's answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a star font family:

```css
.star-rating {
    font-family: star !important;
}
.star-rating span {
    font-family: star !important;
}
```